# Symfony htaccess hiding app.php

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

The following `.htaccess` was able to allow my symfony project domain to be served without `app.php` in the URL, as intended. The only issue is that it is breaking all other (non-symfony related) urls and causing an internal server error.

Right now, after deleting the `.htaccess` file from the server, all my domains work but the project tied to symfony must be accessed using `app.php` in URL ?

Is it possible to modify the below `.htaccess` to rewrite the symfony url to not require `app.php` in the URL while still allowing for all other URLs, not tied to symfony, to be accessed successfully?

Not sure this is needed, but assume the domain tied to symfony is `www.apples.com`.

Thanks in advance!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # Change below before deploying to production
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Edit**
I also tried the following:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteEngine On

        # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
        RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    

        # Change below before deploying to production
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with your htaccess file, are your other URLs also url rewrites?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem with the first `.htaccess` is that it breaks all non-symfony related URLs. The problem with the second `.htaccess` is that all domains work but `app.php` must be included in the URL for the domain tied to the symfony project, so I'm back where I started, it is equivalent to deleting the `.htaccess` altogether. The other URLs are basic non-symfony (`index.php`) URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Right after

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

and set **DirectoryIndex** to **index.php**

Comment: I appreciate the help but I'm sorry to say, I spoke too soon, the `app.php` is still required in the URL after applying these changes.

Comment: Oh! Add [OR] to line checking file.
And it should rewrite to app.php only if there are no requested file or directory.

Comment: sorry, I don't know what you mean, can you please show me an example?

Comment: I've edited my answer with "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems to be working for the URL:) However, none of the css / images / or JS seems to be linking properly after this change to `htaccess`. Any ideas why this might be? I tried clearing the cache.

Comment: Sorry! I'm confused with your edited question. You could not get static files because it checks file OR directory existence. So it should correctly work without [OR]. Please try initial variant.

Comment: THanks for the reply. With the `[OR]` I can access the site without `app.php` in the URL but cannot properly link to images, css or javascript files. Without the `[OR]` which was your intial suggestion, I must include `app.php` in the URL so it `.htaccess` doesn't rewrite the URL (equivalent to not having `.htaccess` at all).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to this game but I just found an Apache directive that saves so much time and makes your htaccess cleaner. The only caveat is you must have Apache 2.2.16+. To have all urls except valid files (images, etc) use app.php as a front controller use the [FallbackResource](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) directive.

```
<Directory "/web/symfony-project">
    FallbackResource /app.php
</Directory>
```